# SQL count all distinct and sub totals

Tags: sql, count, mariadb, distinct

Hi I have a table with the following schema

| ID | companyID | scopeID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 4 | 1 |
| 6 | 4 | 1 |

I want to be able to count the total of companies but also be able to count how many of them are on each scope with a distinct.

For the example of the table the result would be this:

| scopeID | Total_disctinct_companies_of_each_scope | Total_companies |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 |

This means that each scope should count with distinct of companyID but at the same time i want to be able to count the total of companies independent of the scope.

I have been trying to work with over() and partition by but since i don't have that much experience i don't really know how to do it.

I am working with MariaDB.

Thank you so much!!

Comment: How come scopeID has 4 Total_companies? I only see companyID 1 and 3.

Comment: In the table you can see there are companiesID (1,2,3 and 4). Its like a count(distinct(companyID)) without taking into account the scopes. Doing both things in the same query is what leads me into trouble and dont knowing how to do it.

Comment: I see, I thought it was per scopeID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate your total distinct companies separately and then join it to a query that returns the per scope totals.

```
select 
    scopeID,
    count(distinct companyID) total_distinct_companies_of_each_scope,
    total.total_companies
from 
    tmp
join 
    (select count(distinct companyID) total_companies from tmp) total
group by scopeID
```

Returns

| scopeID | total_distinct_companies_of_each_scope | total_companies |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 |